# Instalação lodown

Tags: r

Estou tentando instalar o pacote lodown, mas o seguinte erro aparece e não consigo solucionar:

> ```
>  ERROR: loading failed
>     * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/archive’
>     Installation failed: Command failed (1)
>     '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ  \
>       --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
>       '/private/var/folders/s0/ydk6pxp96xx9_skq6zsgnz7w0000gn/T/RtmplkTXsa/devtools54239183389/ajdamico-lodown-b902889'  \
>       --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library'  \
>       --install-tests 
>
>    ERROR: dependency ‘archive’ is not available for package ‘lodown’
>     * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/lodown’
>     Installation failed: Command failed (1)
> ```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que devo fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Se você está usando o macOS, é necessário concordar com os termos da licença (Xcode/iOS license). Você pode ir ao terminal e rodar o código abaixo:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Depois disso, tente rodar o código para instalar o pacote lodown novamente:

```
devtools::install_github("ajdamico/lodown")
```

Comment: a língua a ser utilizada é o português. Por favor edite sua resposta

Answer (score 4):

Eu acabei de fazer o teste e a instalação aconteceu sem erros.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ajdamico/lodown" , dependencies = TRUE)
```

O pacote `archive`, que deu problema na sua instalação, foi instalado com o auxílio do `Rtools`. Você pode fazer o download [aqui](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).